# Storing/accessing next element in string array in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm trying to print out all the elements of my array based upon what the user enters. I don't think I'm storing them correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 0;
int iChoice = 1;
char cNames[255];
char *iNames[5];

int main()
{
   while (x >= 0 || iChoice == 1) {
      printf("\nPlease enter a name: ");
      scanf(" %s", cNames);
      iNames[x] = cNames;
      printf("Name One: %s", iNames[x]);
      x++;
      if (x > 0) {
         printf("\n\n\tMenu\n");
         printf("\t****\n\n");
         printf("\t1. Enter another name\n\t2. Print report\n\n");
         printf("Enter selection: ");
         scanf("%d", &iChoice);
      }
      if (iChoice == 2) {
         for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
         printf("Name Two: %s\n", iNames[x]);
      }
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Even though I entered 5 different names, it only printed out the very last one I entered 5 times.

```
Name Two: Mike
Name Two: Mike
Name Two: Mike
Name Two: Mike
Name Two: Mike
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: this line: `iNames[x] = cNames;` would be better written as: `iNames[x] = strdup(cNames);`   Then at the of the program: `for(int i=0; i<5; i++ ) free(iNames[i])`

Answer (score 2):

Here you allocate memory for a single string that is 255 characters long:

```
char cNames[255];
```

Let's say that string exists at memory address `42`.

Here you read a sequence of characters into the string at address `42`:

```
scanf(" %s", cNames);
```

If the user enters the name "Joe", the sequence of bytes beginning at memory address `42` looks like this:

```
Joe\0
```

Now we'll store the address of the string in your pointer array:

```
iNames[x] = cNames;
```

`iNames[0]` now looks like this (technically, those zeros are actually random numbers, because we haven't set their values yet):

```
{ 42, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

Now we loop, and read another sequence of characters from the user:

```
scanf(" %s", cNames);
```

What happens here?  `cNames` is still a single string at memory address `42`.  If the user enters the name "Bob", the sequence of bytes beginning at memory address 42 looks like this:

```
Bob\0
```

What happened to the name "Joe"?  We overwrote it.  The iNames pointer array doesn't store the string "Joe"; it stores the memory address `42`.  We overwrote the sequence of bytes at that memory address.

Once the program finishes, what you'll eventually end up with is a pointer array looking like this:

```
{ 42, 42, 42, 42, 42 }
```

To fix this, you need to make sure you allocate a block of memory for each string you're trying to read in.  Do something like this to read the string from the user:

```
char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
scanf(" %s", str);
iNames[x] = str;
```

...and something like this to clean up when the program finishes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    free(iNames[i]);
}
```